# GROUPING SETS and COUNT(DISTINCT)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Good afternoon,

I am working with a sample of data with dimensions for State, County and City. I am measuring personal addresses by social security number. Here is an example of a data set:

```
CREATE TABLE dm_test_case
(
    state varchar(1),
    county varchar(1),
    city varchar(1),
    address int,
    ssn int
);


INSERT INTO dm_test_case (state, county, city, address, ssn)
VALUES  ('a','a','a',100,1),
        ('a','b','b',101,2),
        ('a','b','c',102,2),
        ('a','c','d',103,3),
        ('a','c','d',103,3),
        ('b','d','e',104,4),
        ('b','d','e',105,4);

SELECT  *
FROM    dm_test_case


SELECT   state
        ,county
        ,city
        ,address
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT ssn) AS unique_persons
FROM    dm_test_case
GROUP BY    GROUPING SETS
            (
                (state, county, city, address),
                (state, county, city),
                (state, county),
                ()
            )
```

Of interest in this data set is the following:

- SSN 1 is completely unique
- SSN 2 has 2 addresses in 2 cities
- SSN 3 is a duplicated record
- SSN 4 has 2 addresses in 1 city

Using any combination of grouping sets, the number of unique_persons given by the aggregation is 4. Depending on the groupings, this number may or may not be true (i.e. a person may live in two cities, counties or states).

What method can I use to show a true "sum" of unique_persons--regardless of how the data is grouped--not an aggregated sum?

As an example, I would want the following query to return a value of 5 unique_persons for the grouping set.

```
SELECT   state
        ,county
        ,city
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT ssn) AS unique_persons
FROM    dm_test_case
GROUP BY    GROUPING SETS
            (
                (state, county, city),
                ()
            )
```

I hope this example is clear.

Cheers.

Comment: No it is not clear, you say `5 unique_persons`, but test data contains 4 unique values...

Comment: True, @GiorgiNakeuri; however, when grouping by state, county and city, the number of unique records is 5. SSN 2 appears in 2 cities, while the other SNNs only appear in 1. I believe I stated my situation poorly.

I was able to return the desired result using the following:
`SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT state + county /*+ city*/ + CAST(ssn AS varchar(1))) AS unique_persons
FROM    dm_test_case`

By toggling the usage of city in the above statement, I can select a count of 4 or 5 unique values.